# Etale fundamental group of a curve in characteristic $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fundamental-group

Let $C$ be a connected, smooth, proper curve of genus $g$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$. Let $\pi_1(C)$ be the etale fundamental group of $C$ - I only care about this as an abstract profinite group, so I omit base points.

It is well known by Grothendieck that $\pi_1(C)$ is topologically generated by $2g$ elements. Formally, there is a surjection 
$\phi:\widehat{F_{2g}}\rightarrow \pi_1(C)$, where the first group is the profinite completion of the free group on $2g$ elements. Moreover, if we let $G^{(p)}$ be the prime-to-$p$ quotient of $G$, then
$$\pi_1(C)^{(p)}\cong\widehat{F_{2g}/w}^{(p)},$$  where $w=\prod_{i=1}^g[x_i,y_i].$ I.e., you get what you expect from the characteristic 0 case.

Recall that the prime-to-p quotient is the quotient $G/K$, where $K$ is the intersection of the kernels of all the maps from $G$ to finite prime-to-$p$ groups.

**Question: Is there any case of a curve $C$ of genus at least 2 for which its etale fundamental group is known?**

I phrase the question in this way because the Etale fundamental group does depend on the curve in question. In fact, even its abelianization will depend on the $p$-rank of the Jacobian.

Comment: Tamagawa proved that for all profinite groups $G$, there are only finitely many smooth proper curves over $\bar{\mathbb F_p}$ (up to isomorphism) with etale fundamental group isomorphic to $G$. Maybe you can find something useful in his article; see Finiteness of isomorphism classes of curves in positive characteristic
with prescribed fundamental groups, J. Algebraic Geom. 13 (2004), 675–724.

Comment: Of course (you certainly know this), if you remove $t$ points to your curve, then the problem is solved, provided than $t>0$. It is Abyankhar's conjecture, now a theorem of Raynaud and Harbater.

Comment: @Joël : what you wrote is completely wrong. Abyankhar's conjecture describes *the set of finite quotients* of the $\pi_1$, but since in the affine case the $\pi_1$ is not topologically of finite type, this is not enough information to get back the $\pi_1$. For instance, the $\pi_1$ of $\mathbb A^1$ is not known in positive characteristic, even if one knows that its finite quotients are the quasi-$p$ groups. In fact to my knowledge there is no example of an hyperbolic curve whose $\pi_1$ is "known" in positive characteristic.

Comment: @Niels: Actually, I was wondering about this. Is there an example of 2 non-isomorphic profinite groups with the same finite quotients? Perhaps this is worth posting as a separate question...

Comment: @Niels, Ah okay, interesting. But "completely wrong" is perhaps not the right term (or possibly I am more wrong that you explain in your comment): one at least knows all the finite quotients of this profinite group (the $pi^1$ of a non-complete curve), which is already something important, and sufficient for many applications. Then it depends of what we mean by "know", and apparently the OP was not completely sure about that. But, do we know the complete list of finite quotient of the $\pi^1$ for a curve of genus $\geq 2$ without any point removed ?

Comment: @jacob. The finite quotient of $\mathbb Z_p^I$ for $I$ infinite are all the abelian $p$-group. Now take two infinite sets $I$, one enumerable say and another say larger than the continuum, and you have two profinite groups non-isomorphic (because they don't have the same cardinality) having the same set of finite quotients. So Niels is right that there is more in understanding a $\pi^1$ than its understanding it's finie quotient. Now in algebraic geometry one could have the point of view that it is the finite quotients, corresponding to finite cover, that are what we want to understand.

Comment: @jacob I think I remember you can find an example in Fried-Jarden Field Arithmetic.

Comment: @Joël I agree "completely wrong" was a bit strong :) but I disagree with your interpretation of the question. Clearly the question is : "is the $\pi_1$ known up to isomorphism ?". An answer to your weak version wouldn't answer the following question : "given a fixed finite group $G$, what is the cardinality of the set of $G$-covers" ?

Comment: Aha! That is illuminating. But over a countable field like $\mathbb{F}_{p^{\infty}}$ we know that the set of $G$-covers is at most countably infinite. So in that context, at least, one can answer Niels's question simply by knowing the finite quotients. Am I correct that even in this restricted setting, we do not know the $\pi_1$?

Comment: @jacob I am not sure I understand your third sentence. About the last sentence : the $\pi_1$ of a proper curve is invariant by algebraically closed field extension. So fixing a specific base field does not change the question for proper curves. And the answer is no, the $\pi_1$ is not known. By specialization theory we just know it is topologically of finite type. For affine curves the situation is even worse since the  $\pi_1$ is not topologically of finite type.

Comment: @Niels: You said Joels observation of knowing the finite quotients does not tell us, for a fixed finite group, the cardinality of the set of $G$-covers.My third sentence was meant to say that,if we are working over a countable field, it does. Because the answer is either countable infinity,or some finite number,either of which can be detected on the level of finite quotients.

As you say, this is irrelevant if we are working with proper curves, but if we talk about affine curves this starts mattering. So, my question is: If the $\pi_1$ of a hyperbolic affine curve over a countable field known?

Comment: @jacob: for an affine curve, we just know if a given finite group $G$ arises as a quotient of $\pi_1$ or not and nothing more. In particular the cardinality of the set of $G$-covers is not known for general $G$. And this data would be probably insufficient to recover the $\pi_1$ anyway. To sum up: no the $\pi_1$ is not known for any curve (complete or not) over any field of positive characteristic except for the trivial cases of $\mathbb P^1$ and elliptic curves.

Comment: @Niels: Not to belabour the point, but i think knowing whcih groups $G$ arise suffices to figure out the cardinality of the set of $G$-corvers. The point being that if there are $k$ non-conjugate homomorphisms to $G$, then there is a homomorphism $\pi_1\to G^k$, and the image $H$ of this homomorphism has $k$ non-conjugate homomorphisms to $G$. So we can detect whether theres at least $k$ $G$-covers by asking whether such a group $H$ occurs as a finite quotient.

Probably even this is not enough to determine the profinite group. Perhaps I'll ask this a separate question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take $G_1$ an infinitely generated free $p$-group and $G_2$ the product of $G_1$ with $\mathbb Z/p$. Then they have the same finite quotients but are distinct. This is not so great an example, because group cohomology distinguishes them.

Comment: I think $\pi_1$ is not known for any hyperbolic curve in any reasonable sense. For instance, just knowing for each prime-to-$p$ cover the $p$-rank of its Jacobian seems very hard - it is not at all obvious that there is a usable finite description of this data.